# Mysql SELECT row NOT IN AND GROUP together

Tags: mysql

I have a timetable with 2 tables

```
//user table
id  name
1   ben
2   alex
3   billy
4   john

//schedule table
year    month   date    id
2016    5       15      2
2016    5       22      1 // id 1 - ben want to swap his time with others
2016    5       23      2
2016    5       30      3
2016    5       31      1
2016    5       22      3
```

id 1 - ben wants to swap his schedule with other's ppl.

I need to SELECT name FROM user JOIN schedule and GROUP BY name

than I need those user name don't have any schedule at 2016-5-22

```
//output should be like this
id   name
2    alex //he have schedule at 15, 23
4    john //he don't have any schedule
```

billy and ben have schedule at 22, so they don't show up

I try to write something like

```
SELECT name FROM user LEFT JOIN schedule ON user.id = schedule.id
WHERE year = 2016 && month = 5 && date != 22
```

but this query will still show up billy, because billy have a row in 2016-5-30

Is anyone can help me with this query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to filter groups not rows for your query to work.Simple guide WHERE for rows HAVING for groups

```
SELECT name FROM user LEFT JOIN schedule ON user.id = schedule.id
GROUP BY name
HAVING SUM(year = 2016)>0
AND SUM(month = 5)>0
AND SUM(date=22)=0
```

Or simpler

```
...HAVING SUM(CONCAT(year,month,date)='2016522')=0
```

Comment: why use SUM(year = 2016)>0 ?

Comment: @BenjaminW In mysql year = 2016 or any conditions will translate to 1 if it was found or 0 if not.So it checks for all years where the year is 2016 for each row in that group

Answer (score 1):

The following query will give you all names that are not scheduled to work on 2016-5-22.

```
SELECT A.NAME FROM USER A 
WHERE A.ID NOT IN(
SELECT A.ID FROM USER A, SCHEDULE B 
WHERE (A.ID=B.ID)
AND B.YEAR=2016 AND B.MONTH=5 AND B.DATE=22
)
```